# create new users in openfire via user service plugin using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, openfire

I am trying to write a python program which would add a new user to openfire server . I have enabled user service requests and http basic auth . 
I am getting Response 401 . This is my code

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
def add_controller(name,password):
    xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
    <username>""" + name + """</username>
    <password>""" + password + """<password>
</user>"""
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml','Authorization':'Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU='}
    r = requests.post(url='http://192.168.200.115:9090/plugins/userService/users', data=xml, headers=headers ,auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin','admin'))
    print r

add_controller("test@example.com","test")
```

Comment: It looks like your mixing Basic and Digest auth. My guess is this one is winning auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin','admin').

Comment: @iamads how you get data(messages) from openfire server using python ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used sleekxmpp to connect to openfire https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set two `Authorization` headers. You can do Basic *or* Digest authorization, and the `auth` argument can handle either. Pick one or the other.

Using basic auth:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
r = requests.post(
    url='http://192.168.200.115:9090/plugins/userService/users',
    data=xml, headers=headers, 
    auth=('admin', '12345'))
```

or using digest auth:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
r = requests.post(
    url='http://192.168.200.115:9090/plugins/userService/users',
    data=xml, headers=headers, 
    auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin', '12345'))
```

See the [dedicated *Authentication* chapter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/) of the documentation.

The [Openfire user service endpoint](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html#post-userserviceusers) should work just fine with the basic auth option.

You can more easily create the XML document using templating, and you should really use the [`xml.sax.saxutils.escape()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.escape) to ensure your data is suitable for inclusion in the document:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

xml = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
    <username>{}</username>
    <password>{}<password>
</user>""".format(escape(name), escape(password))
```

Comment: @Matijn I tried as you said but I am still getting Response 400 ,any ideas??

Comment: @iamads: I don't know. The changes I propose certainly make the POSTed information correct for the published specification. Is there anything logged on the Openfire side?

Comment: Finally got it working , had to add the authorization header . Thank you

Comment: @iamads using `auth=...` adds that header. Are you sure your username and password in there are correct? Don't put the new username and password in there?

Answer (score 1):

This is for my future reference , openfire requires the authorization header. My working code is as follows , It adds test user with password as test

```
import requests 
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

def add_controller(name,password):
    xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
    <username>{}</username>
    <password>{}</password>
</user>""".format(escape(name), escape(password))

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml','Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU='}
    r = requests.post(
        url='http://192.168.200.105:9090/plugins/userService/users',
        data=xml, headers=headers, 
        auth=('admin', 'admin')
    )
    print r 

add_controller("test","test")
```

Comment: Your `Authorization` header does the same thing as `auth=('admin', '12345')`. Your `auth` tuple uses `('admin', 'admin') *instead*. So it looks like you just put in the wrong password here; the `Authorization` header is *not needed* if you use `auth=(username, password)` but you do have to put in the correct username and password.

Comment: You can check this yourself: decode the characters after `Basic` as Base64; you'll see that it decodes to `admin:12345`; the username and password separated by a `:`.